# Uso de listas ligadas en Win32 (winapi) C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi

Buen día, me gustaria saber como usar listas doblemente ligadas en Winapi, mas especificamente, ¿donde inicializar la lista? y dentro de los CALLBACK, ¿como usar la lista? (o simplemente al declararla en el lugar correcto se puede usar sin problemas?) Actualemente uso Visual Studio 2015.

En MsgDlgProc solo hay botones para ir a las otras ventanas.

En MsgDlg2Proc, hay 3 Listbox para mostrar los datos de la lista y un boton para regresar a la ventana 1. Para mostrar la informacion pienso usar si logro obtener "nombre" directo de la lista ligada

`SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_LIST1, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, (LPARAM)nombre);`

En MsgDlg3Proc, hay 2 EditControl para recibir los datos y un boton para guardarlos en la lista y vaciar los Editbox y un boton para cancelar

Aqui el codigo:

```
HWND hDlg;
HINSTANCE ghDlg;

struct registro {
    registro *sig;
    int folio; //char en statictext ---> int en lista
    char nombre[70];
    int edad;//char en editcontrol ---> int en lista
    registro *ant;
};

BOOL CALLBACK MsgDlgProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
BOOL CALLBACK MsgDlg2Proc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
BOOL CALLBACK MsgDlg3Proc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

BOOL CALLBACK MsgDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            return true;

        case WM_COMMAND: {
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {

                case IDC_BUTTON1: {
                    ShowWindow(hDlg, SW_HIDE);
                    DialogBox(ghDlg, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG3), 0, MsgDlg3Proc);
                }
                break;

                case IDC_BUTTON2: {
                    ShowWindow(hDlg, SW_HIDE);
                    DialogBox(ghDlg, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG2), 0, MsgDlg2Proc);
                }
                break;

            }
            return false;
        }
        break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hDlg);
            return true;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR cmdLine, int showCmd) {
    hDlg = CreateDialog(ghDlg, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), 0, MsgDlgProc);
    ShowWindow(hDlg, showCmd);
    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));
    while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) {
        if (hDlg == 0 || !IsDialogMessage(hDlg, &msg)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

BOOL CALLBACK MsgDlg2Proc(HWND hDlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            return true;

        case WM_COMMAND: {
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {

                case IDC_BUTTON1: {
                    ShowWindow(hDlg, SW_HIDE);
                    DialogBox(ghDlg, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), 0, MsgDlgProc);
                }
                break;
            }

            return false;
        }
        break;

        case WM_CLOSE:

        DestroyWindow(hDlg);
            return true;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

BOOL CALLBACK MsgDlg3Proc(HWND hDlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            return true;

        case WM_COMMAND: {
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {

                case IDC_BUTTON1: {
                }
                break;

                case IDC_BUTTON2: {
                    ShowWindow(hDlg, SW_HIDE);
                    DialogBox(ghDlg, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), 0, MsgDlgProc);
                }
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
        break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hDlg);
            return true;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Las listas, independientemente de su naturaleza, sirven únicamente para fines propios de tu aplicación.

La API de Windows te sirve un abanico de funciones para interactuar con el sistema operativo. Esta interfaz suele trabajar con handlers, una suerte de identificador que permite acceder a los diferentes recursos del sistema operativo.

En definitiva, las listas enlazadas únicamente van a existir en tu aplicación. El sistema operativo no tiene ninguna necesidad de pedirte o facilitarte listas enlazadas. Si el SO necesita hacer uso de este tipo de estructuras las implementará y gestionará internamente y a ti te facilitará una interfaz más o menos genérica que no va a exponer dichas estructuras. ¿Por qué? Basicamente por los riesgos que supone que se corrompa.

Otro motivo es que una lista enlazada es algo muy abstracto:

- ¿Qué contiene la lista enlazada? Un entero, una estructura, recursos del sistema operativo, ... No puedes crear a la ligera una lista genérica que trate todos los casos posibles en C (interfaz de WinAPI)
- ¿La lista es enlazada simple, doble? ¿Es plana o circular? Demasiadas causísticas posibles
- ¿Quien y cómo gestiona la memoria asociada a dicha lista? Si es la aplicación entonces no tiene sentido que el SO presente una interfaz para su gestion. Si lo hace el SO la aplicación pierde el poder sobre dicha memoria.
- ¿Qué implementación es la más adecuada? El mejor algoritmo de gestión dependerá del uso que se le de a la lista. Es facil entender que pueden existir tantas gestiones como aplicaciones instaladas luego dar una versión genérica no es la solución y dar una específica puede complicar demasiado la interfaz.

Lo que tienes que hacer es ver cómo estructurar tu aplicación para que todas aquellas secciones de la misma que necesiten hacer uso de una lista enlazada puedan acceder a la interfaz que permita trabajar con las mismas. Dicha interfaz puedes o crearla tu de cero o importarla de alguna librería que incorpore dicha característica... pero desde luego no va a ser responsabilidad del SO ni su gestión ni su mantenimiento.

La API del SO la tendrás que usar cuando quieras comunicarte de verdad con el SO.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

> Buen día, me gustaria saber como usar listas doblemente ligadas en Winapi

Como ya indica [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13059/2742)<sup>1</sup>, el uso de una lista doblemente enlazada es independiente al uso de WinAPI. En otras palabras: el uso de la herramienta es independiente de la tarea. Por poner una alegoría: es lo mismo usar un destornillador para cambiar un enchufe que para desmontar un mueble de Ikea®, el destornillador sigue sirviendo para lo mismo.

Por otro lado, aparentemente estás reinventando la rueda al crear tu propia lista con la estructura `struct registro` (que según veo en tu código ni siquiera estás usando); C++ te ahorra el trabajo de desarrollar tu propia lista doblemente enlazada al ofrecerte en la librería estandar de plantillas (stl) una implementación: [`std::list`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) (el resaltado es mío):

> `std::list` es un contenedor que soporta inserción rápida y borrado de elementos de cualquier parte del contenedor. No es rápida en acceso aleatorio. **Está implementada como lista doblemente enlazada**.

Sigamos...

> mas especificamente, ¿donde inicializar la lista? y dentro de los CALLBACK, ¿como usar la lista? (o simplemente al declararla en el lugar correcto se puede usar sin problemas?) Actualemente uso Visual Studio 2015.

Sin conocer exáctamente lo que buscas, podrías declarar la lista como global en el mismo ámbito que `hDlg` o `ghDlg`, lo cuál te permitiría acceder a la lista desde cualquier parte del mismo archivo:

```
HWND hDlg;
HINSTANCE ghDlg;
struct registro {
    int folio = 0; //char en statictext ---> int en lista
    std::string nombre = "";
    int edad = 0;//char en editcontrol ---> int en lista
};
std::list<registro> lista;
```

Cuando necesites guardar datos en la lista deberás hacer algo así:

```
// Leer datos
int folio = LeerFolio();
std::string nombre = LeerNombre();
int edad = LeerEdad();

// Guardar datos
lista.push_back({folio, nombre, edad});
```

Cuando necesites leer datos de la lista deberás hacer algo así:

```
// Por cada elemento contenido en la lista...
for (const auto &r: lista)
{
    // Mostramos el folio del elemento.
    std::cout << "Folio: " << r.folio << '\n';
    // Mostramos el nombre del elemento.
    std::cout << "Nombre: " << r.nombre << '\n';
    // Mostramos la edad del elemento.
    std::cout << "Edad: " << r.edad << '\n';
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Para variar se me adelanta eferion al responder, es más madrugador que yo o escribe más rápido.